# Scan outgoing traffic for sensitive data

Tags: linux, windows, security, proxy, firewall

I run Windows on my desktop, but I would be willing to route my traffic through a Linux box if required.

I've had two instances of my credit card being misused in two months now. Despite being careful it seems that some site has leaked the information. I scanned my PC for virus/malware/keylogger/rootkits using various tools, but nothing bad found.

This got me thinking I should set up some sort of monitoring of outgoing traffic. The simplest type would simply look at the initial x KB of a connection to see if it contains my credit card / any of my passwords. A more complex system could prevent the packets from even being sent. A sort of "sensitive data shield".

I thought Norton Internet Security had this, but installing their trial of the 2016-version I can't find the feature. I also tried searching the web for software like this, but can't find anything.

Anyone know of firewall/proxy software that will do this?

Comment: Most credit cards are not compromised by the user themselves, they are compromised by an identity that user has used in the past, very few in reality actually get infected with rootkits designed to capture credit card numbers.

Comment: Yes, I have compiled a list of places that I used my card and sent it to my bank. But I'd still like to add the extra protection to my system. :)

Comment: Well Norton does have the feature, the problem is, the feature itself breaks HTTPS in order to provide it.  Fiddler also breaks it.  There is no secure way to scan HTTPS traffic without breaking it.  The reason I bring up HTTPS is because malware authors are smart. HTTPS is not expensive to implement, they are using it to secure the communication between infected hosts and the command server.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at this piece of software: [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)

Fiddler can intercept and record HTTP(S) traffic, and you can search through it with any filters. You can even set breakpoints to automatically interfere with traffic that matches a filter.

Comment: Fiddler is good for web debugging (actually, its great), but not good for long term use. It both eats up a lot of memory and it will pop up error messages every now and then. I want it running 24/7 without it affecting my internet speed / memory usage too much.

Answer (score 1):

This is called Extrusion Detection https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extrusion_detection

It's problematic in two regards:

1. TLS/HTTPS connections
2. the attacker encoding information before sending it out

You can get around 1 by creating your own certificate and installing it in the trusted store(s) on your machine, and using a proxy like Charles, to dynamically creates certs (signed by your own cert) for you, effectively MiTM-ing yourself. However a sophisticated bad guy could get around that by using Certificate Pinning.

You can try to get around 2 by creating many encodings of your credit card number and searching for them (like base64, reversed, ROT13, etc)

You can use a tool like Snort to monitor your network traffic. It usually runs on a machine connected to a port on your switch that is setup for mirroring